# Missing Custom Layout in Sub Site

Tags: page-layout

I have globally deployed a branding solution that contains a number of page layouts.  The web application where I want to use this contains a top level site collection and a number of sub site collections.  All of which need to utilized these layouts.  However, for reasons not apparent to me,  the sub site collections do not provide the ability to choose a newly create layout. Also, the gallery in the sub site collections do not list the newly added layout.

I am looking for solutions/suggestions that will help solve why these layouts are not listed as expected.  I hope I have provided enough information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you deployed your page layout in the right way? Page layouts are deployed in a different way than the master pages, for the master page to be deployed, you can just point to the catalogs folder inside your module and that's it, they will be deployed, but for the page layouts you will need to add additional properties to the module to configure them to be able to use them in the site.

You would need to add "PublishingAssociatedContentType" to the File entry inside your Module.

You can see a step by step here:

http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-create-page-layout-in-sharepoint.html

and this is also a link to see what am talking about:

http://historiesofsharepointlover.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/capture61.png

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In the root site(Site Collection),Go to *Site Settings>Look and Feel>Page layouts and site templates*.
Under *Page Layouts*, Select *Pages in this site can use any layout* and Check *Reset all subsites to inherit these preferred page layout settings*.Press Ok.

In the subsites,Go to *Site Settings>Look and Feel>Page layouts and site templates*.
Under *Page Layouts*,
ensure that the option *Pages inherit preferred layouts from parent site* is selected.

Comment: Thanks.. We tried this but one of the problem s it that in the sub site the layout is not listed in the select box.  So even resetting the subsites it does not recognize our layout to reset to.... if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you need to follow while normally attaching a page layout for a page.

1. Create a custom page layout in SPD, by copying an existing layout and editing the same.
2. Once completed, the new page layout should be checked in, published and approved.
3. Go to Site settings -> Look and feel ->Page layouts and Site templates -> Specify the page layout that is created in the page layouts section, if the site has been given specific layouts.
4. Now you will be able to see the layout while creating a new page.

There is a small confusion in the question above though. Are you using sub sites or separate site collections for subsites, since you have said sub site collection. If those are sub sites mapped from different site collections, the publishing feature in these site collections needs to be enabled and then the page layout must be uploaded into these separately. Please correct me if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Yes they are site collections as sub sites and the publishing feature is enabled which makes this more puzzling.   One note though, I am deploying these layouts from a Visual Studio created wsp solution and not using Designer in this case.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Make sure your WSP is deployed into each sub site collection and also that the page layouts are present in each separate 'master page and page layout' gallery (Checked in , published and approved) of the sub sites and do the step 3 above on each of them. Everything should work then.

Comment: Hope this got resolved.

Comment: Thanks Deepu.  So far that is the problem.  The page layouts are not present in some of the site collection sub sites.  The wsp is globally deployed.  I am not sure yet what else to do to have the layouts propagate to the subsites.