# Unable to locate Subsite Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page

On our company intranet page,I have created a subsite that I am having trouble editing the page layout. Previously when creating the home page I was able to located the page layouts in SPD2010 and edit (Blank Web Part Page), but when I open SPD2010 under the new subsite nothing appears when selecting Page Layouts from the navigation pane.

How do I edit the page layout for the subsite?

Answer (score 1):

Try directly from SP, taken from this [link](https://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2007/05/31/change-what-page-layout-you-are-using.aspx):

- Browse to the page
- Click Site Actions, Edit Page
- From the tool bar click Page
- In the drop down list click Page Settings
- Now pick your Page Layout
- Click OK

Or, see [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47299/custom-page-layout-is-not-available-on-sub-sites) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25092/missing-custom-layout-in-sub-site) related posts.

Answer (score 0):

PageLayouts are stored in the list at the root of the site collection.  Please be aware that they are shared amongst all sub-sites so if you make a change to one that is used on the different sites the change will be reflected everywhere.

Alternatively you could create a new layout and use it on just the one site.

Comment: any recommended articles on creating a new page layout?

Comment: Using SPD2010 you can simply cut and paste the one you currently referenced and make the required changes.  Then follow the instructions dzookatz made to associate your page with the new page layout.